# Access Database is not connecting on running exe file

Tags: java, database, ms-access, netbeans-8

I have connected access database using following set of code

```
String database="Neuro.mdb";
String url="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" +    database + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true";
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
stmt=con.createStatement();
```

I have placed access files in netbeans project folder but when I run its exe file in dist folder database shows no connection its data is not displayed.

Comment: try to do this inside `try-catch` and make some `println("connection is successfull)` to check weather you really connected to the DB or not

Comment: I have included all  blocks in my code they are doing fine inside netbeans but when I run jar fire alone its not working there.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting database file at root folder of project